# jQuery .hasClass returning false when it shouldn't be?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery `.hasClass` is being invoked

For reference:  `alias = '2983_pirrota_1011_A20_Input%2820cyc%29_773_CEL'` which is also the `id` of the element.

```
if ($('#' + alias).hasClass('selected')) {
   alert ("true");
} else {
   alert ("false");
}
```

However this is returning `false` when it should be returning a `true` since it is a member of that class!. I used the `escape()` function in javascript to escape special characters for the value of alias. As soon as I remove the `%` (which is how `escape` and `encodeURIcomponent` encode special characters) it starts working fine. Is this a known issue or is there a simple way around it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, its a known thing. You need to escape special characters with 2 backslashes: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Is there a jQuery function that does this automatically? Since the strings are generated dynamically.

Comment: No, just use a `alias.replace('%', '\\%')` to escape them (you can expand this to include more characters).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($('#' + alias.replace(/%/g, "\\\\")).hasClass('selected')) {
   alert ("true");
} else {
   alert ("false");
}
```